App Development: Calling another binary executable
Introduction
I want to call another binary executable file when I start my app. This app is on Magic Leap (Am Android Device with x86_64 CPU).
This bin file will generate a txt file with content "hello, world!". I can use ADB to run this binary file under /data/local/tmp, which may prove that this file can run on Magic Leap.
But I can not cd to app private path, while the app cannot call file under /data/local/tmp. And I cannot call the file in my app. I tried system() and execvp() and they both doesn't work. Kindly note that I want use pure C++ and NDK to realize this.
Below is my code.
void checkFilePermissions(const char* filePath) {
        if (access(filePath, X_OK) != -1) {
            ALOGI( "File has execute permission: %s" , filePath);
        } else {
            ALOGI( "File does not have execute permission: %s" , filePath);
        }
}
int executeBinary(const char *filePath) {
        char *args[] = {strdup(filePath), nullptr};
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
        ALOGI( "execvp failed: %s" , strerror(errno));
        return -1;
         }
        return 0;
}

void OnStart() override {
        const char *filePath = "/data/data/com.magicleap.capi.sample.eye_tracking/files/bin/hello";
        checkFilePermissions(filePath);
        int result = executeBinary(filePath);
        if (result == -1) {
            ALOGI("Failed to execute binary.");
        } else {
            ALOGI("Binary executed successfully with exit code: %d", result);
        }
... // other code
}

Below is the Log:

File has execute permission: /data/data/com.magicleap.capi.sample.eye_tracking/files/bin/hello


execvp failed: Permission denied


Failed to execute binary.

